# distance from a point to line segment not it 's perpendicular line's distance

Tags: geometry

[image]

how to find distance between line and point in the picture ?

what is the shortest distancing point in the line ?

Note: distance between line and point means line segment,(the intersecting point must fall into the line segment)

Answer (score 2):

Denote $V_3=(x_3,y_3)$ the point in the corresponding line, such that  $V_1V_2\perp V_0V_3$:

$$
(x_3-x_0)(x_2-x_1)+(y_3-y_0)(y_2-y_1)=0.\tag{1}
$$

Since $V_3$ is on the line, then there is $p\in \mathbb{R}$, that
$$
x_3 = x_1+(x_2-x_1)p;\\
y_3 = y_1+(y_2-y_1)p.\tag{2}
$$

If $V_3$ belongs to segment $V_1V_2$, then $p\in[0,1]$.

So, we need:

- to find $p$ from $(1),(2)$;${}^{(*)}$
- if $p\in[0,1]$, then shortest distance is $|V_0V_3|$, otherwise it is $\min\{|V_0V_1|,|V_0V_2|\}$.

---

${}^{(*)}$ How to find $p$: substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$, we get linear equation:

$(1),(2) \Rightarrow$
$$
(x_{01}+x_{12}p)x_{12}+(y_{01}+y_{12}p)y_{12}=0,
$$
where $x_{ab}=x_b-x_a$, $y_{ab}=y_b-y_a$;
so
$$
(x_{12}^2+y_{12}^2)p + x_{01}x_{12}+y_{01}y_{12}=0;
$$
$$
p = \dfrac{x_{01}x_{12}+y_{01}y_{12}}{x_{12}^2+y_{12}^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ be the endpoints of the segment and $P$ the given point. The result depends on whether the angles $\angle PAB$ and $\angle PBA$ are obtuse or acute. After a short calculation we have that
$$d(P, AB) = \begin{cases}\|P - A\|, & \text{if } (P - A) \cdot (B - A) \le 0 \\
\|P - B\|, & \text{if } (P - B) \cdot (A - B) \le 0 \\
\|P - \frac{((P-B) \cdot (A-B)) A + ((P-A) \cdot (B-A)) B}{\|A-B\|^2}\|, & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the parametric equation of the line $P=P_1+tP_1P_2$ and express orthogonality of $P_0P$ and $P_1P_2$:
$$(P_0P_1+tP_1P_2)\cdot P_1P_2=0,$$
giving
$$t=-\frac{P_0P_1\cdot P_1P_2}{(P_1P_2)^2}.$$
If $t\le0$ (projection of $P_0$ outside the segment, on the side of $P_1$), return
$$||P_0P_1||,$$
else if $t\ge1$ (projection of $P_0$ outside the segment, on the side of $P_2$), 
return $$||P_0P_2||,$$
else return 
$$||P_0P||.$$
[There is a special case, when $P_1=P_2$: just return $||P_0P_1||$.]